# Уточняющее обстоятельство образа действия

Tags: уточнения, обстоятельство

### Ещё нужно обнаружить проблему, мешающую запустить аппарат нормально, без каких-либо сбоев.

Можно ли считать, что "без каких-либо сбоев" уточняет обстоятельство образа действия "нормально"?

Answer (score 2):

Обстоятельства считаются **уточняющими**, если несут дополнительную информацию об образе совершения действия, причем эта информация имеет более конкретный характер.
*Она одевалась уныло, по-старушечьи. Только так, в тишине, она могла работать.*

Мне думается, что в этом предложении обособленное обстоятельство является **пояснением.**
Пояснение — это обозначение одного и того же понятия разными словами ("нормально" — это и есть без сбоев).
Для введения пояснительного члена используются сочинительные пояснительные союзы *а именно, именно, то есть, или (= то есть)*.
Если эти союзы не употреблены в предложении, они могут быть вставлены.

Если немного перестроить предложение, то можно поставить тире.
Ещё нужно обнаружить проблему, мешающую нормально запустить аппарат — без каких-либо сбоев.

[«Хитрые» члены предложения (об уточнении, присоединении и пояснении)](https://www.portal-slovo.ru/philology/37431.php?ELEMENT_ID=37431&PAGEN_1=2)

Answer (score 2):

Можно ли считать, что "без каких-либо сбоев" уточняет обстоятельство образа действия "нормально"?

**Да, так можно считать, что видно из правила Розенталя:** http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118#pp118

Обособляются (выделяются запятыми, реже — тире) слова и словосочетания, уточняющие смысл предшествующих слов (**уточнение — это переход от более широкого понятия к более узкому**). Чаще всего уточняются обстоятельства и определения.

***Нормально, без каких-либо сбоев.*** ***Нормально*** — это общее понятие, ***без  каких-либо сбоев*** — это конкретизация.

Далее у Розенталя:http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118#pp118

Различие между уточняющими и пояснительными членами предложения заключается в том, что если уточнение — это переход от более широкого понятия к более узкому, то пояснение — это о**бозначение одного и того же понятия другими словами.**

Такое толкование в приведенном предложении **тоже возможно,** и иногда подобные отношения можно считать **уточняюще-пояснительными,** тем более что  в обоих случаях второе слово обособляется (пунктуация одинаковая).

Но Розенталь пояснительные отношения связывает с наличием **союзов**, а при их отсутствии обособление обычно делается **с помощью тире.** (При отсутствии пояснительного союза вместо запятой перед пояснительным членом предложения часто ставится тире).

В данном предложении союзов нет, ставится запятая.